# view MDX query from SSMS

Tags: ssms, ssas, mdx

Any chance I can see the query generated when I'm browsing a cube through SSMS?
I supposed I could run a trace on the DB to capture it, but just wondering if there is an easier way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about SSMS (other than trace) but there is an add in for excel which allows you to see the MDX generated on pivot tables. The MDX is sort of similar:

http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using the **SQL Server Profiler** you could see the query generated. Just connect to Analysis Services server and save the trace.

Comment: I said on the question "I supposed I could run a trace on the DB to capture it, but just wondering if there is an easier way". I know I can do that, just looking for an easier way.